# Render StringBuilder HTML in MVC 3 View

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, view, stringbuilder

In my view I am looping through my model and building html to display on the page. I am building this html with stringbuilder and if/else conditions.

I have tried to render this string as html but I keep getting stuck.

This is the code:

```
@model UserManager.Models.vw_UserManager_Model 
<div id="success-message">
    <fieldset>
        <legend><b>@ViewData["Action"]</b> </legend>
        <!-- User created -->
        <div id="content">

            @Html.Raw("some test string");

            @{
                System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                int i = 0;
                sb.Append("<ul>");
                foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    string s = item.ToString();
                    if (s == "," && i != 1)
                    {
                        // When it finds first delimiter, start building the string
                        i = 1;
                        sb.Append("<li>");
                    }

                    else if (s == "," && i == 1)
                    {
                        // When it finds first delimiter, start building the string
                        sb.Append(" : ");
                    }

                    else if (i == 1 && s != "/")
                    {
                        // Contine building the string
                        sb.Append(s);
                    }

                    else if (s == "/")
                    {
                        // End current list item and set i to 0. This will start the next li sequence
                        sb.Append("</li>");
                        i = 0;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        // Do nothing in the loop   
                    }
                }
                sb.Append("</ul>");
                var str = MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());

            }

        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Contents of SB

```
{<ul><li>firstname : sdlmsdm</li><li>lastname : smsd</li><li>salutation : Mr</li><li>password : ksklsd</li><li>email : sdkm@as.com</li><li>userName : sdkmsdmke</li><li>MaxConcurrentUsers : 0</li><li>group_name : [PIAS] UK LTD</li><li>module_name : Connect:Top 1000 Advertisers</li><li>isactive : True</li><li>IsApproved : False</li><li>alf : True</li><li>brad : False</li><li>selected_moduleAlf : Connect:Top 1000 Advertisers : System.String : selected_moduleBrad : false : </ul>}
```

I can't see anything of the HTML once this code is finished debugging. Does anyone have the answer?

Comment: You mean str is empty after debugging?

Comment: @slacker str isn't empty because on the breakpoint I have a body of HTML which I built with my loop.

Comment: Last li tag is not closed

Comment: @slacker good spot. I will modify my loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you are not writing it. You need to do `@Html.Raw(str)`:

```
sb.Append("</ul>");
var str = new HtmlString(sb.ToString());

@Html.Raw(str)
```

Comment: It didn't work. I don't understand why my html isn't rendering. I will edit my post with the new code.

Comment: Are you sure you have a good value in your `Model`. Looking at your code I think you can have this as an example `a,b,c,d`, right? Why don't you return an "expected valid string" from your controller so you can check that the "view code" is working.

Comment: I think the values in the stringbuilder are not valid. I hardcoded a string and that works fine. I will check that again.

Comment: I ended up using a string variable instead of a stringbuilder obj and I made sure I closed all my li's and the ul and it has worked. Plus I used @Html.Raw(). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad it worked. But honestly though, you should NOT have any logic on your views. You should either build the string in your controller or best is have an htmlhelper extension and build your string with it.

Comment: But I am building HTML in the view. The only reason I have loops is because I added an enumerator for my model and each loop returns a character. So I parse it based on the logic.

Comment: "But I am building HTML in the view." - that's where html helpers can help you. [See this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs) to get more idea about it. Once you get the idea use `TagBuilder` to build your html.

Answer (score 1):

Change your HtmlString to an MvcHtmlString.Create("string") and then just display the created variable.

```
<div id="content">
    @{
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<ul>");
        sb.Append("<li>asdfd</li>");  
        sb.Append("</ul>");
        var str = MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());

    }

    @str
</div>
```

Comment: There's no need to use MvcHtmlString. You can output properly formatted html to a view using `Html.Raw`.